# mips recursion how to correctly store return address for a function

Tags: mips

I have a problem passing the correct address in a recurssive function in mips

I have a main function I can't alter that goes essentially sets up values and calls my function like this:

```
jal findX
```

my function performs calculations on floats and does  the following:

```
findX:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   #make room on stack
sw $ra, 0($sp)      #save ra

#a series of calculations that are not part of the problem
jal evaluate #gives an output based on the calculations before that triggers various branches

bc1t x_return

jal findX

x_return
mov.s   $f0,$f17    #holds the value to return
lw      $ra, 0($sp) #restore $ra
addi    $sp, $sp, 4 #restore stack pointer
jr  $ra
```

The problem is that once the correct values are found it appears that my return address is messed up and "jr $ra" calls the function again instead of returning. How do I fix this I think I am following mips recursive convention correctly.

Comment: Does your ABI have the stack pointer point to the first empty slot on the stack or the last used slot?

Comment: *Application Binary Interface*. Among other things, it specifies how functions call each other, which registers to preserve, how to pass arguments that are too large for registers.

Answer (score 1):

Your push/pop code in `findX` is fine and is ABI conforming. And, the pre-subtract of `$sp` *always* works regardless of ABI.

You're not showing `evaluate`, but it's the likely suspect. If you had, it would be fairly easy to examine the code and diagnose the problem.

Upon a *true* return, `evaluate` either has changed `$sp` or has overwritten parts of the `findX` stack frame.

You can add a breakpoint in `evaluate` for the true case. Most simulators keep a history of the last N instructions, so you can look at changes to `sp` or stores relative to it. That may be enough.

But, another way, is to add some debug code to `findX` that works in conjunction with the debugger. That is, the failure condition may be too complex for the debugger to stop on (i.e. it doesn't have sophisticated *watch* conditions like `gdb`), so we can add some "helper" code.

I've added some extra values to the `findX` stack frame that allow for some consistency and cross-checking and extra code to check these values

Below is your code modified for debug.

Using the debugger, put breakpoints on *all* the `nop` instructions. When you hit one, examine the history, values, etc. This should help isolate your problem.

```
# recursive debug

findX:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-12             # make room on stack

    sw      $ra,8($sp)              # save ra
    sw      $sp,4($sp)              # save sp
    li      $t7,0xdeadbeef          # save a "magic" number
    sw      $t7,0($sp)              # we want this at the old offset for sp

    # a series of calculations that are not part of the problem
    # gives an output based on the calculations before that triggers various
    # branches
    jal     evaluate

    # NOTE/BUG: if this returns "true", then one of two things happened:
    # (1) evaluate changed the sp register contents
    # (2) evaluate overwrote the the return value we stored above

    bc1t    matchfound

    jal     findX

x_return:
    li      $t7,0xdeadbeef          # get the expected magic number
    lw      $t6,0($sp)              # get the stored value
    bne     $t6,$t7,badnews1        # did it get trashed? if yes, fly
ignore1:

    # the sp value must be the same as when we called the function
    lw      $t6,4($sp)              # get the stored value
    bne     $t6,$sp,badnews2        # did it get trashed? if yes, fly
ignore2:

    # NOTE: we take advantage of the fact that evaluate is called from only
    # _one_ place within findX, so we _know_ the ra value
    la      $t7,x_return            # get the expected return value
    bne     $ra,$t7,badnews3        # did it get trashed? if yes, fly
ignore3:

    # NOTE: we take advantage of the fact that evaluate is called from only
    # _one_ place within findX, so we _know_ the ra value
    la      $t7,x_return            # get the expected return value
    lw      $t6,8($sp)              # get the saved return value
    bne     $t6,$t7,badnews4        # did it get trashed? if yes, fly
ignore4:

    mov.s   $f0,$f17                # holds the value to return

    lw      $ra,8($sp)              # restore $ra

    addi    $sp,$sp,12              # restore stack pointer
    jr      $ra

# trap for success
matchfound:
    nop                             # put a breakpoint here
    j       x_return

# trap for error
badnews1:
    nop                             # put a breakpoint here
    j       ignore1

# trap for error
badnews2:
    nop                             # put a breakpoint here
    j       ignore2

# trap for error
badnews3:
    nop                             # put a breakpoint here
    j       ignore3

# trap for error
# NOTE: this one is special
# we may get a false positive on the first call to findX
# that is, (e.g.) main does "jal findX" and so we'd fail here
# for that case, just continue
badnews4:
    nop                             # put a breakpoint here
    j       ignore4
```