# MIPS32 Stackframe broken?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, mips32

So here the code as wished:

PROGRAM 1

```
.text
  .globl main
  main: 
    li     $t0, 10
    mtc1    $t0, $f12
    cvt.s.w $f12, $f12               # 10.0 as single in $f12
    jal     printFloat      

    li      $v0, 4001               #sys_exit
    syscall

printFloat:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        cvt.d.s $f12, $f12              #converts the single to double
        la      $a0, strDouble          #arguments needed for printf ("%f" in $a0, upper 32 bit of the float in $a2, lower ones in $a1)
        mfc1    $a1, $f12               
        mfc1    $a2, $f13               
        jal     printf                  
        jal     fflush                  

        la      $a1, strBreakLine       #arguments needed for printf (Adress of String in $a1, "%s" in $a0)    
        la      $a0, strStringOut       
        jal     printf                  
        jal     fflush                  

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

.data
strDouble:      .asciiz "%f"
strStringOut:   .asciiz "%s"
strBreakLine:   .asciiz "\n"


phm15fix@ci20:~$ gcc -o test -g test1.s
phm15fix@ci20:~$ ./test
10.000000
```

PROGRAM 2

```
.text
.globl main
main: 
        li     $t0, 10
        mtc1    $t0, $f12
        cvt.s.w $f12, $f12               # 10.0 as single in $f12
        jal     printFloat      

        li      $v0, 4001               #sys_exit
        syscall

printFloat:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        cvt.d.s $f12, $f12              #converts the single to double
        la      $a0, strDouble          #arguments needed for printf ("%f" in $a0, upper 32 bit of the float in $a2, lower ones in $a1)
        mfc1    $a1, $f12               
        mfc1    $a2, $f13               
        jal     printf                  
        jal     fflush
        jal     printNewLine                  

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

printNewLine:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        la      $a1, strBreakLine       #arguments needed for printf (Adress of String in $a1, "%s" in $a0)    
        la      $a0, strStringOut       
        jal     printf                  
        jal     fflush 

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

.data
strDouble:      .asciiz "%f"
strStringOut:   .asciiz "%s"
strBreakLine:   .asciiz "\n"


phm15fix@ci20:~$ gcc -o test -g test1.s
phm15fix@ci20:~$ ./test
10.000000
Bus error
```

PROGRAM 3

```
.text
.globl main
main:
        li     $t0, 10
        mtc1    $t0, $f12
        cvt.s.w $f12, $f12               # 10.0 as single in $f12
        jal     function

        li      $v0, 4001               #sys_exit
        syscall

function:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        jal     printFloat

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

printFloat:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        cvt.d.s $f12, $f12              #converts the single to double
        la      $a0, strDouble          #arguments needed for printf ("%f" in $a0, upper 32 bit of the float in $a2, lower ones in $a1)
        mfc1    $a1, $f12
        mfc1    $a2, $f13
        jal     printf
        jal     fflush
        jal     printNewLine

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

printNewLine:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            #opens the stack frame
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #saves the return adress

        la      $a1, strBreakLine       #arguments needed for printf (Adress of String in $a1, "%s" in $a0)
        la      $a0, strStringOut
        jal     printf
        jal     fflush

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #restores the return adress
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #pops the stack frame
        jr      $ra

.data
strDouble:      .asciiz "%f"
strStringOut:   .asciiz "%s"
strBreakLine:   .asciiz "\n"
```

At the end of every program is the specific output.

The first program works fine.
In the second program I made an extra function for printing a new line. If I run this I get a "bus error".

And in the third program I made a dummy function to simulate another stacklevel.
There is also a "bus error" and the number i want to print is not printing.

I think there are some problem with our stack.

I used the debugger and if I load my return-address from stack I have the wrong address in my $ra and i dont know why. If it jumps to this address i get the "bus error".

Here are the functions:

```
PRINT_DOUBLE:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             

        la      $a0, strDouble          
        mfc1    $a1, $f12               
        mfc1    $a2, $f13               
        jal     printf                  
        nop
#       lw      $a0, stdout
#        jal     fflush                  
        jal     BREAK_LINE

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             
        jr      $ra


BREAK_LINE:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             

        la      $a0, strBreakLine
        jal     PRINT_STRING

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             
        nop

        jr      $ra

PRINT_STRING:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            
        sw      $ra, 0($sp)             

        add     $a1, $a0, $zero         
        la      $a0, strStringOut       
        jal     printf                  
        la      $a0, stdout
        lw      $a0, 0($a0)
        jal     fflush                  

        lw      $ra, 0($sp)             
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4             
        nop
        jr      $ra
```

Comment: This might not be related to your problem, but why are you using `printf("%s", "\n");` rather than just `printf("\n");` (or even simpler: `puts("");`) ?

Comment: Generally, SO folks will be very unhelpful unless you put your code into your actual question using a minimal code example. Pastebin and other links aren't helpful.

Comment: Also, use the debugger to at least pinpoint the exact place for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked over your program and most of it looks fine. I think your stack save/restore is fine. But, I see at least one other problem.

After every `jal printf`, you're doing an *immediate* `jal fflush`, so `fflush` will get printf's first argument [which is a string pointer] instead of a file descriptor pointer (e.g. `stdout`).

Under the mips ABI, the `$a0-$a3` registers may be modified/destroyed by the *callee*. So, after `printf` returns `$a0` can be anything.

All three programs seem to have this problem. IMO, if program 1 is working, it's just the luck of the draw (i.e.) whatever ends up in `$a0` is harmless enough. That is, whatever is in it, points to a memory location that isn't a file descriptor but `fflush` tries to interpret it as one and lucks out.

Also, for `fflush`, `$a0` should point to an address that is word [4 byte] aligned. If it's not, that could be the source of the bus error.

To fix this, change all `fflush` calls to:

```
lw     $a0,stdout
jal    fflush
```

That should probably work, but, depending on what the `gcc` assembler does, you may have to do:

```
la     $a0,stdout
lw     $a0,0($a0)
jal    fflush
```

---

> I've seen that the buserror appears if I try to jump back from a function For example I jump to PRINT_DOUBLE, there I jump to BREAK_LINE and there I jump to PRINT_STRING If I jump then back to BREAK_LINE all is fine, but back from BREAK_LINE to PRINT_DOUBLE I get the buserror

I've desk checked your code and [once again] seems fine. One way to debug this is to [using `gdb`] is to single step [with `stepi`] within your functions and put breakpoints after the the `jal printf` [or `jal fflush`].

Before and after each `jal`, note the `$sp` value. It *must* be the same. Do this for all your functions. Also, when returning from a function, note the `$sp` value, then the value from the `lw` [which goes into `$ra`]. They should all match the "expected"

Further, `$sp` must be 4 byte aligned at all times. Actually, according to a mips ABI document I've seen [possibly dated], it says that stack frames must be 8 byte aligned. That may be overkill at this point, but I mention it.

If you do `lw` from unaligned, that's an alignment exception, which will probably show up as `SIGBUS`. Further, check the `$ra` value [*before* doing the `jr $ra`]. It also must be the "expected" value and be 4 byte aligned.

In other words, *exactly* which instruction produces the exception?

Another thing you can do is to comment out some function calls. Start with the `jal fflush`. Then, comment out `jal printf` [in your sub-functions]. I note that you do a "naked" `printf` call at the outset, which seems fine. Keep doing this until the program stops faulting. This ought to help localize the area/call.

You didn't state whether you were running this in a simulator like `spim` or `mars` or real H/W [possibly running linux]. I suspect real H/W. But, you could verify *your* logic by running under a simulator [I prefer `mars`] and provide dummy functions for `printf` and `fflush` that just do `jr $ra`. Note that neither `spim` nor `mars` can link to `.o` files. They work purely from source, so you can only use your `.s`

If you're running on real H/W, `gdb` ought to be able to provide detailed information on the source of the exception. If not, create a C function that sets up a signal handler for `SIGBUS` using `sigaction` [see the manpage]. Then, put a breakpoint on the signal handler.

One of the arguments to the signal handler is a pointer to a `siginfo_t` struct that has additional information. Note that for `SIGBUS`, the `si_code` field will have a `BUS_*` value that may have more information.The third argument, although `void *` is a pointer to something that can give you the register values at the time of the exception.

In another answer I gave: [mips recursion how to correctly store return address for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505854/mips-recursion-how-to-correctly-store-return-address-for-a-function/36524095#36524095) another OP had a similar problem. My answer added some special stack alignment and check code that may give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks for your advise, I use this construct now...
but I've seen that the buserror appears if I try to jump back from a function
For example I jump to PRINT_DOUBLE, there I jump to BREAK_LINE and there I jump to PRINT_STRING
If I jump then back to BREAK_LINE all is fine, but back from BREAK_LINE to PRINT_DOUBLE I get the buserror

I made a new code-snippet in the question